# How to use Switch with dictionary values?

Tags: c#, dictionary, switch-statement

In my code, I'd like to work with textual names of the items that are coded as one symbol in packets.

In a usual situation, `1012` would mean `cat, dog, cat, frog` to me, but there are many more pairs like this, so it's hard to remember all of them. Sometimes they need to be changed, so I thought I should use a `Dictionary<string, int>` for that purpose. But then…

```
switch (symbol)
{
    case "0": { /* ... */ }
    case "1": { /* ... */ }
    case "2": { /* ... */ }
    case "n": { /* ... */ }
}
```

…becomes…

```
switch (symbol)
{
    case kvpDic["cat"]: { /* ... */ }
    case kvpDic["dog"]: { /* ... */ }
    case kvpDic["frog"]: { /* ... */ }
    case kvpDic["something else"]: { /* ... */ }
}
```

and the studio says I need to use constants for my switch.

How do I make it work?

**Upd**: number of such *animals* and their value pairs are only known at runtime, so the code must not use constants (I guess).

Comment: What are you doing in the switch blocks? Basically you *won't* be able to switch on non-constant values, so you'll need to think of *some* alternative. There are various options, but we'll need more information.

Comment: Have you thought of using an `enum` instead?  Or do the values change at runtime?

Comment: I assign Texture2D to a new sprite and they are unique to each situation.

Comment: What are you doing inside the case blocks?

Comment: It sounds like that could be wrapped in a single method and what's returned from your dictionary could be passed in. Can you post an example?

Comment: @scottm it's pretty simple, but most cases are unique, as I said. A texture is assigned to an object, sometimes to multiple objects, they are then marked to be animated and some checks are made to prevent possible bugs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could store a `Func<T>` or `Action` in the dictionary instead.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Action>();
dict.Add(1, () => doCatThing()); 
dict.Add(0, () => doDogThing());
dict.Add(2, () => doFrogThing());
```

Then, use it like so:

```
var action = dict[1];
action();
```

Comment: "Action Dictionary" just sounds cool.  Sounds like something I'd hear in a kids cartoon.  Don't fear the Action Dictionary is here!

Comment: @Servy: Sounds like something you'd use to scare the crap out of children ;)

Comment: Awesome! Though it took me some time to understand how exactly it works and plug possible holes.

Comment: Don't you guys think it's a bit of a bad practice to use an "Action Dictionary"?
Shouldn't you try to decouple the code more?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a VS restriction, it's a language restriction. So you won't be able to do exactly what you want. One idea would be to use an enum. An enum can't use a char value for it's entries, look at [Why we can't have "char" enum types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572963/why-we-cant-have-char-enum-types) for some info on that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an enum, not a dictionary.

```
enum AnimalsEnum { Dog, Cat, Bird, Fish };


public whathuh(AnimalsEnum whichAnimal) {
 switch(whichAnimal) {
   case AnimalsEnum.Dog:
   case AnimalsEnum.Cat:
...
}

}
```