# Why is Enum.GetValues better than iterating?

Tags: c#, enums, enumeration

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/enumerate-an-enum) answer

> By the way, incrementing the value is not a good way to enumerate the
>   values of an enum. You should do this instead.
>
> I would use `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit))` instead.

Why? How is `GetValues` better than iterating?

Comment: Where does it say such thing?

Comment: I don't see anyone incrementing values in the linked question or in one of it's answers. So i don't understand [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/105421/284240).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @knittl stated:

> Because you can have "holes" in your enum. Consider ***enum E { A = 1, B =
>   2, C = 4 }***. Incrementing will yield **A, B, 3, C** enumerating over all
>   values will yield **A, B, C**

and thanks to @Andrei for pointing out:

> enum might be defined with any values. Even with [chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10203473/728795). So
>   incrementing might give you a lot of stuff that is no in the enum.
>   GetValues is guaranteed to return only relevant values though

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you misunderstood the context there.

Poster of the answer you are referring to suggests to use `GetNames` to iterate through **names** of the enum. But than he says that when it comes to **values** enumerating over `GetValues` is better than incrementing.

So one is not better than the other, they serve different purposes well, and author of the answer outlines this.

Comment: _enumerating over GetValues is better than incrementing_. Why?

Comment: @adoomedknight: Because you can have "holes" in your enum. Conside `enum E { A = 1, B = 2, C = 4 }`. Incrementing will yield `A, B, 3, C`, enumerating over all values will yield `A, B, C`

Comment: @adoomedknight, to add to what knittl said, enum might be defined with any values. Even with [chars](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10203473/728795). So incrementing might give you a lot of stuff that is no in the enum. `GetValues` is guaranteed to return only relevant values though