# How to extract the values of all of the constants in an enum - into a char array?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, enums

It's possible extract values in `enum` to `Char[]`?

I have the `Enum`:

```
enum eTypeLanguage { typed = 'T', functional = 'F' }
```

How to extract values `eTypeLanguage` to `Char` array?

Comment: @CodeCaster Convert `Enum` to `Char` Array.

Comment: I want to convert all fields

Comment: I think you are confused as to what this is actually doing, if you did `Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(YourEnum))` it would return int32

Comment: @Sayse but it [works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572963/why-we-cant-have-char-enum-types). :-)

Comment: A pure fluke perhaps :) Just hoped to show the op that they aren't actually working with characters

Comment: It was a good question, but sadly it didn't get that much attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you are looking for this (It returns `string[]`):

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(eTypeLanguage));
//returns: typed, functional
```

If your are looking for values ('T', 'F') then you may do this (this won't throw `System.InvalidCastException` for your enum):

```
 var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(eTypeLanguage))
                  .Cast<eTypeLanguage>()
                  .Select(i => (char)i).ToArray();
 //returns: 'T', 'F'
```

Comment: No, OP is not asking for the names of the enum's members.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get all enum members' char values, you need to call `Enum.GetValues`, cast the returned value to the acutal enum type, then cast each member from its enum type to `char`:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(eTypeLanguage))
                 .Cast<eTypeLanguage>()
                 .Select(e => (char)e)
                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: Oh apologies I missed that bit! still if they have integers it might not work as they expect :) (not that they should)..

Comment: @MeuChapeu edited, apparently you need to cast `Enum.GetValues()` response to the actual enum type.